Error when running npx create-expo-app - npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function with Node v20.15.1
When I try to create a project with the command npx create-expo-app MyProjectName -t
I get the following error:
npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\myuser_\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2024-12-27T18_46_03_227Z-debug.log
Install for [ 'create-expo-app@latest' ] failed with code 1

Does anyone know why this is happening?
I’m using Node version v20.15.1
